# Why doesn't CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS find clock_gettime in CMake?

Tags: c, cmake

How come `CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS` doesn't find `clock_gettime`?

I use the following code in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include(CheckFunctionExists)

set(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES time.h)
CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS(clock_gettime HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
```

This is on a POSIX system I know has `clock_gettime`. Yet I simply get:

```
-- Looking for clock_gettime - not found
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `clock_gettime` is found in `librt` we need to link to that when doing the check (otherwise CMake will simply fail to compile the test program it generates to test if the function exists).

This is not possible with `CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS`. Instead **CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS** must be used:

```
include(CheckLibraryExists)
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(rt clock_gettime "" HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
```

This will now work and output:

```
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt - found
```

**Update**: In newer glibc 2.17+ `clock_gettime` has been moved from `librt` to `libc`.

So to be sure to find `clock_gettime` on all systems you would need to do two checks:

```
include(CheckLibraryExists)
CHECK_LIBRARY_EXISTS(rt clock_gettime "" HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)

if (NOT HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
   set(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES time.h)
   CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS(clock_gettime HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
   SET(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES)
endif()
```

Comment: This will change with the glibc 2.17 release. The clock_* symbols are being moved into libc and code will no longer need to link against librt.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I am using:

```
include(CheckFunctionExists)
include(CheckLibraryExists)
check_library_exists(rt clock_gettime "time.h" HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
if (HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -lrt")
    set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES "${CMAKE_C_STANDARD_LIBRARIES} -lrt")
else()
    # might also be in libc
    check_library_exists(c clock_gettime "" HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
endif()
```