# clock_gettime not found on Mac OSX 10.11.6

Tags: c, macos, cmake, clock

I am trying to build I-Simpa on the Mac.

When I try and build at the spps stage, I get errors about `clock_gettime` not found. I tried altering the CMakelists.txt in the spps directory as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747505/why-doesnt-check-function-exists-find-clock-gettime-in-cmake):

```
check_library_exists(rt clock_gettime "time.h" HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)

if (NOT HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
    set(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES time.h)
    CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS(clock_gettime HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
    SET(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES)
endif()
```

But I then get the error:

> Unknown CMake command "CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you altered [this part](https://github.com/Ifsttar/I-Simpa/blob/master/src/spps/CMakeLists.txt#L58) of the CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (UNIX)
  include(CheckLibraryExists)
  check_library_exists(rt clock_gettime "time.h" HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME )
  if(NOT HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "clock_gettime not found")
  endif(NOT HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
endif(UNIX)
```

As you can see, `check_library_exists` is known by CMake because the corresponding module has been previously included using `include(CheckLibraryExists)`.

Again, that is just a guess, but I am pretty sure you didn't included the module for `CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS`. Try:

```
check_library_exists(rt clock_gettime "time.h" HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)

if (NOT HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
    #**************************#
    include(CheckFunctionExists)
    #**************************#
    set(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES time.h)
    CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS(clock_gettime HAVE_CLOCK_GETTIME)
    SET(CMAKE_EXTRA_INCLUDE_FILES)
endif()
```

This removes the "Unknown CMake command" error, but `clock_gettime` is not available on Mac OS. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x) for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks 

Adding include(CheckFunctionExists) stopped the unknown Cmake function error but I still get CMake Error at src/spps/CMakeLists.txt:68 (message):
  clock_gettime not found

I am trying to do this on a Mac and ideas what the Cmake file should look like?

Comment: Looks like `clock_gettime` isn't available in Mac OS. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167269/clock-gettime-alternative-in-mac-os-x) for alternatives

Comment: Many Thanks saved me a lot of time